# How to skip StopFilter for one-word value

Tags: java, lucene

I want to create my own Analyzer but only apply StopFilter for multiple-word value, and still index the stop word with one-word value (the stop word itself)

```
new Analyzer() {
            protected Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
                final StandardTokenizer src = new StandardTokenizer();
                TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(src);
                tok = new LowerCaseFilter(tok);
                tok = new StopFilter(tok, StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET);
                return new Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents(src, tok);
            }
        }
```

Example, I have 2 value:

```
1. this
2. this table
3. table
```

With above Analyzer, and query string is "this", no result was found. But I want with that query, the result should contain value 1 (**this**), and not contain value 2 (**this table**)

Comment: Which version of lucene are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
...
final StandardTokenizer src = new StandardTokenizer();
src.setReader(new StringReader("this table")); 
...
```

Comment: StandardTokenizer does not work as I want, pls read my question again

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for it, you would need to build your own StopFilter.

Comment: Ya, I know, and I want to ask how to build my own, because in the Filter implement, I don't know how to determine the full indexed text

Comment: You can't know the whole input from a filter. You would have to write a token filter that buffers the first token if it is a stop word, and then restores it if there are no more tokens.

Comment: plz give me some code? I have a litle knowdge on lucene